# (How) can I correctly add a utility sink to this washing machine drain setup?

Tags: drain, sink, washing-machine, pump

The Background:

Shown here, the lovely setup behind my unfinished-basement washing machine. This was all installed just before we bought the house a few years ago, because the sewer is about a foot too high for the washer to dump directly into the pipe per code.
[image: Photo of existing washing machine drain and pump]
On the left, the discharge hose from the washer goes into the drain standpipe, through a P-trap into a drain pump, [Liberty Model 404](https://www.libertypumps.com/wp/dom/Products/Drain-Condensate-Pumps/Drain-Pumps/model404) (pump not found heh heh). The drain pump has a vent pipe on the back, which goes up and out of frame, and a discharge with a check valve ([Jackel DJ-545](http://jackel.com/dj-545.html)) on the front, which goes up to to the main sewer line, just out of frame on the wall above. This is an automatic pump; when some amount of water drains into it from the washer, it clicks on with a WHOOSH and blasts the water up to drain into the top of the big sewer line - runs a couple times per wash cycle, for a few seconds each time. My jurisdiction uses the 2018 International Residential Code without amendments. Don't worry, the GFCI breaker for that laundry outlet is just across the room, though I do plan to move it a little farther from the drain pipe.

The Question:

I want to add a utility sink to the left of the washing machine, centered about 5ft from that standpipe drain. An advanced computer rendering of my plan is shown here.

[image: Photo of existing drain setup, with planned utility sink addition crudely pasted on top]

- Can I run it into this existing drain setup, by cutting and inserting a wye-and-bend into that vertical drain?
- I'd want to put a screw-type P-trap under the sink, to catch anything before it gets to this glued-up trap. Would a second P-trap there be *mandatory*,  *prohibited*, or *optional*?
- Would I need an additional vent for the sink, or would the combination of the vent on the boost pump and the not-sealed laundry drain be enough?
- The pump is rated to pass 3/8" solids, but I can't find any similar rating for the check valve. Am I dooming this little graywater check valve and need to upgrade it to a blackwater-type valve, or is it fine for a utility sink? Don't plan to send any solids down the sink, but want to be prepared for whatever inevitably slips past the strainer.

Comment: Correctly? Go back in time and buy the 404L with 2" inlet. That 2" to 1-1/2" reducer downstream is bad news and a code violation in a drain. As for traps, the output of the sink trap will need to meet the drain pipe on the other side of the washing machine trap. And with the 1-1/2" inlet you'll need a separate vent connection that the washing machine can get away without, because it's close enough - but your sink isn't.

Comment: Would an AAV work for the sink?